# Easyadmin how adding Menu Items not Based on Entities?

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I would like in **EasyAdmin 4** at the menu level to add an element which allows to display a pdf containing the instructions for use of the administration. I can't find a tutorial. Do you know how to do it ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In method `configureMenuItems` in your `DashboardController` add link to route with the PDF. Like following:

```php
<?php

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\MenuItem;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractDashboardController;

class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{
    // ...

    public function configureMenuItems(): iterable
    {
        return [
            MenuItem::linkToRoute('PDF', 'fa ...', 'route_name'),
        ];
    }
}
```

It can be found in the official documentation: https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/dashboards.html#route-menu-item

You can also use `MenuItem::linkToUrl` if you don't have route for the PDF file.